# Are there non-trivial settings where the MAD statistic has a closed-form density?

Tags: distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, median, mad

The [MAD statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) of an iid sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is defined as the median of the absolute deviation from the median:
$$
\text{mad}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\text{med}\left\{|x_i-\text{med}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)|;\ i=1,\ldots,n \right\}\,.
$$

I wonder if there exist non-trivial (continuous) distributions on the $X_i$'s such that the distribution of $\text{mad}(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ can be obtained in closed form (cdf or density).

The next level of unknown is the derivation of the *joint* density of the median and the MAD statistics for an iid sample of size $n$.

Comment: For uniform distributions and $n=3$, for instance, the PDF is $f(t) = 6 (1 - 4 t + 4 t^2)$ for $0\le t \le 1/2$. As $n$ increases it gets progressively more complicated.

Comment: For logistic distributions with scale parameter $1$, and $n=3$, the PDF is $$f(t)=\frac{12e^m(e^{3m}+2e^{2m}-e^m-2-m(3e^{2m}+2e^m+1))}{(e^m+1)^2(e^m-1)^4}$$

Comment: For Laplace distributions with scale parameter $1$, and $n=3$, the PDF is $f(t)=3e^{-3m}(e^m-1/2)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the uniform distribution, twice the MAD among $2n-1$ samples seems to have
the same distribution as the $(n-1)^{th}$-smallest of those samples.

The calculation can be done as
$$F(m)=(2n-1)! \int_{A_m} dx_1\ldots dx_{2n-1}$$
where
\begin{align}
A_m = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_{2n-1}): \ &0< x_{1}< \cdots < x_{2n-1} < 1 \\
&\ \& \, \min(g_1, \ldots, g_n)<m\}
\end{align}
and $g_i = \max(x_{(i+n-1)}-x_{(n)},x_{(n)}-x_{(i)})$

I conjecture that the result is always $F(m)=I_{2m}(n-1,n+1)$,
where $I$ is the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), and I have verified this for
$n=2,3,4,5,6$. If so, the intepretation of this in terms of the order statistics is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions), and the corresponding pdf is
$$f(m)=\frac{2(2n-1)!}{n!(n-2)!}\, (2m)^{n-2}(1-2m)^n.$$

I hope someone will be able to find a simple argument that this conjecture is correct.